# Dev-c++ compile errors object

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void){
int n1,k1;
int tot;
    scanf("%d",k1);
    scanf("%d",n1);

    tot=((k1=1)?((n1(n1+1))/2):((n1(n1+1))/2)-((k1(k1+1))/2));
    return 0;
}
```

this code is wrong?

Compiling it with Dev c++, gives me the error **"called object is not a function"** refered at

```
 tot=((k1=1)?((n1(n1+1))/2):((n1(n1+1))/2)-((k1(k1+1))/2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should pass the pointers to variables to the `scanf` functions using `&` operator:

```
scanf("%d",&k1);
scanf("%d",&n1);
```

Secondly, you should correct mistakes in the syntax of your expression:

- use `==` instead of `=` to check equality
- explicitly use `*` operator if you want to perform the multiclication.

`tot=((k1==1)?((n1*(n1+1))/2):((n1*(n1+1))/2)-((k1*(k1+1))/2));`